# Appirater Usage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, appirater

I have added [Appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater) to one of my projects. Appirater is ARC enabled out of box, as far as I can see, but I had the issue with the delegate, I had to synthesize it myself. That is not the problem though.

This is the code I added into my app delegate:

```
[Appirater setAppId:@"0101010101"];
    [Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:-1];
    [Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:-1];
    [Appirater setTimeBeforeReminding:2];
    [Appirater setDebug:YES];
    [Appirater appLaunched:YES];
```

For what I can see, after I pressed rate the app, Appirater should not ask for rating the app any more, there is no functions in it to set that user pressed "Rate". Pressing remind me later button should disable the Appirater alert for 2 days (see setTimeBeforeReminding:) but that does not work neither. Everytime I re-open the app, It just prompts me to rate my app, no matter what I click. Any ideas on how to use this class or a walkthrough?

Note: Using current version of appirater which is update 23 days ago, also has a class AppiraterDelegate, which I have not used.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, people say it to me all the time but it's worth remembering... RTFM

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you set debug to `YES` it will ask to rate everytime you open the app.
Set it to `[Appirater setDebug:NO];`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to test on real device not simulator and do what @jcesar suggested which is set `[Appirater setDebug:NO];`

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [Appirater appEnteredForeground:YES];
}
```